# Share Existing Host Directory with Docker Container?

Tags: docker, nvidia, file-sharing

Docker allows a directory to be shared among other containers with the -v option.

But it shadows any existing directory on the host.

## How can a host directory be made visible to the docker instance?

For example, this creates a mountpoint at `/opt`:

```
nvidia-docker run -i -t --name x nvidia/cuda:7.5-runtime-ubuntu14.04 -v /opt
```

But it shadows the host /opt. This is the safe, usually-desired behavior. But for development and instance setup, it would be immensely useful to have access to an existing file structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make your host files visible within your container, you need to specify:

```
<host_path>:<container_path>
```

So in your case:

```
docker run -it --name <whatever> -v /opt:/opt
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Now I can see all the host files, as well as create files that the host can see.