# How can a host, and a Docker container running on the host, share a common directory for both reading and writing?

Tags: docker

I have read [Share Existing Host Directory with Docker Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42144996/4376643) which covers a mutually *readable* directory but not mutually *writable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read [Share Existing Host Directory with Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42144996/4376643) which covers a mutually readable directory but not mutually writable.

1. Summary

   In the Dockerfile, container group write permissions are enabled by appending `umask 002` to `.bashrc` inside the container.

   On the host side, as shown in 3.1, create a new group with a special id, and add the host user that group, and as shown in 3.2. set the directory and file permissions of the targeted directory and all its subdirectories and files.
2. Create the Dockerfile:

   ```
   FROM ubuntu
   ARG USERNAME=username
   ARG USER_UID=1000
   ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID
   # Add user
   RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
       && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME
   # Enable group write flags for every file the user creates
   RUN su $USERNAME -c "echo 'umask 0002' >> /home/${USERNAME}/.bashrc"
   ```
3. Host side settings.

   3.1. Create a new group and the host user to it.

   Note:  In the testing environment, `ubuntu 20.4`, used by this author, the group id of files created by `username` which appears as `1000` inside the container, appears as `100999` outside of the container.  This mapping is likely to vary by system.

   On the host create a group with gid 100999, and add the host user to that group.  It is necessary to log out and log back in again for it to take effect.

   ````
    ```
    sudo addgroup --gid 100999 g100999
    sudo usermod -a -G g100999 craig
    ```
   ````

   3.2. Set the directory and file permissions of the targeted directory and all its subdirectories and files.

   Ensure the whole directory and all its subdirectories have group read, write, executable, and setuid permissions.

   ````
    ```
    sudo find . -type d -exec chmod g+rwxs {} +
    ```
   ````

   Ensure the all files in all subdirectories have group read and write permissions:

   ````
    ```
    sudo find . -type f -exec chmod g+rw {} +
    ```
   ````
4. Create the container

   ```
   docker build -t testi .
   docker run --rm -u 1000:1000 -d -it --name testc --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/targetdir testi
   docker attach testc
   ```

   From within the container

   ```
   username@154d42ef5260:/$ cd targetdir
   username@154d42ef5260:/targetdir$ ls -alt
   total 24
   drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     4096 Apr 24 16:34 ..
   drwxrwsr-x 2 username username 4096 Apr 24 16:12 .
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 username username  432 Apr 24 15:56 Dockerfile
   ```

   From the host outside the container the same directory looks like

   ```
   $ ls -alt
   drwxrwsr-x 91 craig  craig   4096 Apr 22 15:41 ..
   drwxrwsr-x  2 100999 g100999 4096 Apr 24 09:12 .
   -rw-rw-r--  1 100999 g100999  432 Apr 24 08:56 Dockerfile
   ```

   You should be able to create, write, and delete the files in that directory from either the host or the container sides.

This was tested with:

- Docker version 23.0.4, build f480fb1
- Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS